# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Tags: php

I'm getting an Error in MYSQL

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

Can someone explain to me what is this error all about? thanks.

PHP CODE:

```
<?php

$link = connectToDB();
 $strXML = "<chart caption='Factory Output report' subCaption='By Quantity' pieSliceDepth='30' showBorder='1' formatNumberScale='0' numberSuffix=' Units'>";




    $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT DISTINCT PROFILE FROM tbljocreator GROUP BY PROFILE");
    $show = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    if($result) {
    while ($ors = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    $strQuery = "select PROFILE, sum(MT) as totalLM from tbljocreator where PROFILE =" .$ors['PROFILE'];
    $result2 = mysqli_query($link, $strQuery) or die(mysqli_error($link));
    $getresult2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2); 


    $strXML .= "<set label='" . $ors['profile'] . "' value ='" . $getresult2['totalLM'] . "' />";


    mysqli_free_result($result2);
    }
    }
    mysqli_close($link);
    $strXML .= "</chart>";

        echo renderChart("FusionCharts/Column3D.swf", "", $strXML, "JoCreator", 450, 300, false, true);

    ?>
```

Please explain in clearly for me.

Comment: is PROFILE field a int field ? if not you need to add single quotation marks to represent strings

Comment: Can you expain it for me?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like `$ors['PROFILE']` is an empty variable.  Do a `print_r($ors)` somewhere and also change your query to `$strQuery = "select PROFILE, sum(MT) as totalLM from tbljocreator where PROFILE = '" .$ors['PROFILE']."'";` so that it will not throw that error next time.

By the way, just as an explanation, the error is because if the variable is empty, the query ends after the `=`.  Since it expects a parameter here, it is throwing the error.  Since the errors only show the very beginning of the issue which is at the very end of your query, it's an empty string. (near '')

Comment: I've done what you said it post this error


    Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause

Comment: @user2958635 Then try `$strQuery = "select PROFILE, sum(MT) as totalLM from tbljocreator where PROFILE = '" .$ors['PROFILE']."' Group By PROFILE"`

Comment: this error showed after I put GROUP BY 


    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'X25' GROUP BY PROFILE' at line 1

Comment: @user2958635 I'm sorry, I won't be able to help troubleshoot anymore without more database table information.  Can you post your table info in your question?

Comment: here it is

Column Information

FieldTypeComment
PROFILEvarchar(255) NULL
DETAILvarchar(255) NULL
COLORvarchar(255) NULL
GAUGEdouble NULL
WIDTHdouble NULL
LENGTHdouble NULL
QUANTITYint(11) NULL
LMdouble NULL
MTdouble NULL
REFSOvarchar(255) NULL
JODATEdate NULL
STATUSvarchar(255) NULL
JONUMBERvarchar(255) NULL
PROD_GROUPvarchar(255) NULL
PostingCodeint(11) NULL
UNITvarchar(100) NULL

Comment: @user2958635 Can you post your full new query?  Did you copy/paste what I have above or just add in the new stuff?  Sounds like you are still missing a single quote.

Comment: what kind of information you want? the COLUMN INFO, INDEX INFO OR DDL INFO?

Comment: Your query.  The sql statement.  `$strQuery = "select PROFILE, sum(MT) as totalLM from tbljocreator where PROFILE = '" .$ors['PROFILE']."' Group By PROFILE";`

Comment: @user2958635 No, I want you to paste your SQL statement...  The query you are using to pull your data.